# Automatically add key to Python dict

Tags: python

I want to automatically add keys to a Python dictionary if they don't exist already.
For example,

```
a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"

dict = {}
dict[a][b] = c # doesn't work because dict[a] doesn't exist
```

How do I automatically create keys if they don't exist?

Comment: egidra = EGIdrA = SC2? +1 on name alone

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
def recursively_default_dict():
    return collections.defaultdict(recursively_default_dict)

my_dict = recursively_default_dict()
my_dict['a']['b'] = 'c'
```

Comment: I am too slow in the mornings +1

Comment: `recursively_default_dict = lambda: defaultdict(recursively_default_dict)`

Comment: @X.Jacobs: “Sparse is better than dense. Readability counts.” —[The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 6):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
d['a']['b'] = 'c'
```

Also, please be careful when using `dict` - it has a meaning in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Answer (score 2):

For short scripts you can also use this one liner:

```
d = {}
d.setdefault(a, {})[b] = c
```