# python recursive add keys to dict when edit dict

Tags: python, python-2.x

Need to change in dictionary

```
d1['a']['b']['c'] = 1
```

but it is possible what

`d1['a']['b']` is nonexistent so must be recursively added

Expected results

```
d1={} will be {'a':{'b':{'c':'1'}}}
d1={'a':{'b':{'c':'0'}}} will be {'a':{'b':{'c':'1'}}}
d1={'f':1,'a':{'h':'1','b':{'d':'1'}}} will be {'f':1,'a':{'h':1,'b':{'c':'1','d':'1'}}}
d1={'f':1,'a':{'b':{'c':'0','d':'1'}}} will be {'f':1,'a':{'b':{'c':'1','d':'1'}}}
d1={'f':1,'j':{'h':'1','b':{'d':'1'}}} will be {'f':1,'a':{'b':{'c':'1'}},'j':{'h':'1','b':{'d':'1'}}}
```

Ugly way is

```
if not 'a' in d1.keys():
    d1['a'] = {}
if not 'b' in d1['a'].keys():
    d1['a']['b'] = {}
d1['a']['b']['c'] = 1
```

But I want pretty recursive solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13151294/8580711), but for editing existent dict.

Comment: actually `a = lambda: defaultdict(a)`

Comment: Performance note : `"a" in d.keys()` is O(N) -, while `"a" in d` is O(1).

Comment: "a" in d.keys() is O(N) -, while "a" in d is O(1)
will work only with python 3

Comment: a = lambda: defaultdict(a).
d1 is not empty. question is about how to edit EXISTING dict

Comment: Any reason you can't just use defaultdict and load the values over?

Comment: The other thing you could do is override the methods of your existing dict with methods from `collections.defaultdict`. Sort of a scary zombie takeover.

Comment: As I wrote I already have not empty dictionary. I need to edit it